# i want to extract the value from html tag using sed

Tags: sed

i want to extract the value from html tag using sed

file:

```
<td class=xl7128074></td>
  <td class=xl7128074></td>
  <td class=xl7128074></td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=21 style='height:15.75pt'>
  <td height=21 class=xl8428074 style='height:15.75pt;border-top:none'>ANT</td>
  <td class=xl10028074 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>$interoprfbcheck_prodconnectorstatus_ANT</td>
  <td class=xl8228074>ANT</td>

  <!-- This is set by Python -->
  <td class=xl155577 style='border-left:none;font-size:11.0pt;color:#006100;          
  font-weight:400;text-decoration:none;text-underline-style:none;text-line-through:       
  none;font-family:Arial;border-top:none;border-right:1.0pt solid windowtext;             
  border-bottom:1.0pt solid windowtext;border-left:1.0pt solid windowtext;
  background:#E6EFCE;mso-pattern:black none'>
GREEN</td>
  <td class=xl7128074></td>
  <td class=xl7128074></td>
  <td class=xl7128074></td>
```

I want the expected result:

```
ANT
$interoprfbcheck_prodconnectorstatus_ANT
ANT
GREEN
```

I was using `sed -n 's/<td.*>\(.*\)<\/td>/\1/p' filename.html`
and getting below result:

```
ANT
$interoprfbcheck_prodconnectorstatus_ANT
ANT
```

the GEEEN is not coming, I think because it is not in same line, 
 is there any thing we can add to get the result of next line as well?

Comment: If you wish to preserve your sanity, you should not attempt to process XML with line-oriented tools like `sed`. Try something like `xmlstarlet` or `xsltproc`.

Comment: this is reflecting the desired result 
sed -n 's/.*>\(.*\)<\/td>/\1/p' filename.html.

can anyone pls let me know if it is the correct command to finding pattern ending with '</td>

Comment: Yes, it is. But `sed` will look at one line at a time, and the closing tag is not on the same line, so the pattern as a whole will not match.

Comment: Don't parse XML or HTML [with regular expressions](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/).  It [doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6751105/137158)

Comment: `tr -d '\n' <filename.html | sed 's/<\/td>/<\/td>\n/g' | sed -n 's/.*<td[^>]*>\([^<]\+\)<.*/\1/p'` ... but can obviously easily break. (E.g. some comment, malformed html, td tag holding another tag etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `html2` as a "preprocessor" for sed:

```
$ html2 <file 2>/dev/null | sed '/td=/!d;s/^.*td=//'
ANT
$interoprfbcheck_prodconnectorstatus_ANT
ANT
 GREEN
```

Comment: +1. `html2` is a fairly obscure tool so it's worth pointing out that it's in the `xml2` package.  or, if not packaged for your OS, the source is available at http://ofb.net/~egnor/xml2/

Answer (score 0):

`GREEN` is not coming as it is placed by the generator on a separate line, so your `sed` script does not find a match. Without special arrangements `sed` pulls the incoming stream into the match space line by line.

So, you need to pull into match space new lines with `N` command until you get closing `</tr>` in there, then store a copy of pattern space in a hold space, remove leading `<tr ...>` tag and remove everything starting from `</tr>` up to the end of match space and print it.

After this you need to replace the match space with content of the hold space, remove the already printed part and start over again with looking for leading `<tr ...>` tag.

see `info sed` for details

Answer (score 0):

The HTML sample you posted is not valid XML for several reasons. If that were fixed, however, you could use this:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//td[text()]' input.html
```

The result is not exactly what you expect, since the text of the last non-empty `td` is not `GREEN`, but `\nGREEN`.